# how to show a message after a node form is submitted

Tags: 7, status-messages

How do I show a message (notice or alert) **after** the node form is submitted and saved?

I'm writing a module that synchronizes the node content with a remote endpoint. All working good. But, if for any reason the sync fails, I want to show a message on the page the user is redirected to.

My problem is that I don't find the hook or function which is invoked **after** the form is saved to databases but **before** the redirect happens, where I hopefully can set the message I want.

Comment: Hello. Have you tried anything? Is there any code we can see? And have you seen the api docs for [`drupal_set_message`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7)?

Comment: My problem is that I don't know where to put a call to `drupal_set_message`. I'd like to know if there's a hook I can call **after** the form has been saved to database but **before** the redirect.

Comment: So you want some kind of a confirmation step? Please see if my answer is sufficient or not yet.

Comment: @FabrizioRegini See [`hook_node_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) and [`hook_node_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7) for node API methods, or [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) if you'd rather alter the submission of the node add/edit form itself

Comment: I did already @Clive but what I understood is that they are triggered either **during** a transaction or **before** the query is saved to db.

Comment: Might be an idea to add your code to the question, it'll help to understand what you're trying to do. Why does your message need to be set outside of the transaction in particular? You understand that you can't stop a transaction right in the middle, then show a message, then resume the transaction again afterwards? Or am I misunderstanding what you're asking?

Answer (score 4):

You can create an additional submission callback.  Not sure if it will run late enough for you.  May be worth a shot.

Create a form alter hook using hook_form_alter();
Within there add an additional submit function to the #submit array

Example:

```
hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_submit_function';
}

function custom_submit_function($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('your message');
}
```

You could try going 1 step further and adding the submit hook to #submit in the #after_build.  This will ensure it is the very last submit callback (unless other higher weighted modules also use the afterbuild)

Example:

```
hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#after_build'][] = 'custom_afterbuild_function';
}

function custom_afterbuild_function($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_submit_function';
}

function custom_submit_function($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('your message');
}
```

I hope this helps

[update] added drupal_set_messages to code examples.